# Turn array of object into cummulative dictionary Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary

I have structure called `person`

```
struct person{
   var name : String
   var score: Int
}
```

Then I create an array called 
`let people : [person] = [person("a", 1), person("a", 3), person("b", 5)]`

As you can see, there are two objects with the same name "a" here.

Now I would like to turn this one into a cumulative dictionary, that shows the total score of each person. In this case 
`dict = {"a": 4 (3+1), "b": 5}`

I know I'm violating the OO design rules. 
Thanks

Comment: by the way, type names should be `UpperCamelCase` in Swift.

Comment: `let people = [("a",1), ("a",3), ("b", 5)].map(Person.init)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a fundamental modelling issue here. Your struct `person` doesn't actually model a person. It models something like a `RoundResult`.

I would refactor this by making a `Player` that truly models a person, (with only fields like `name: String`), and make a `RoundResult` that contains a `winner: Player` and a `score: Score`.

```
struct Player: Hashable { // Perhaps should be a class, if names aren't unique.
    let name: String
}

struct RoundResult {
    let winner: Player
    let score: Int
}

let playerA = Player(name: "a")
let playerB = Player(name: "b")

let roundResults = [
    RoundResult(winner: playerA, score: 1),
    RoundResult(winner: playerA, score: 3),
    RoundResult(winner: playerB, score: 5),
]

let scoresByPlayer = Dictionary(grouping: roundResults, by: \.winner)
    .mapValues { roundResults -> Int in
        let scores = roundResults.lazy.map(\.score)
        return scores.reduce(0, +)
    }

print(scoresByPlayer)
```

From here, you can add a `score` variable on player, which *actually* models the players score, not just a single sliver of it from a single round/game/match/whatever

Comment: If this answer has solved your question, please mark it as accepted using the checkmark on the left

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this in two steps: 1) group into a dictionary, and 2) sum scores of the grouping:

```
// grouping = { "a": [person("a", 1), person("a", 2)], "b": [person("b": 3)]
let grouping = Dictionary.init(grouping: people, by: { person in person.name })

let dict = grouping.mapValues { group in 
   group.reduce(0, { sum, person in sum + person.score })
}
```

Or in its shorter, but more cryptic form:

```
let d = Dictionary.init(grouping: people, by: { $0.name })
                  .mapValues{ $0.reduce(0, $0 + $1.score ) }
```

Comment: `let dict: [String: Int] = .init(people.map{($0.name, $0.score)}, uniquingKeysWith: +)`

Comment: @LeoDabus Nice! Better

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are new to Swift. Let me walk you though a few iterations of this.

The most basic is the straight forward approach.

```swift
var dict = [String: Int]()

for person in people {
    if let score = dict[person.name] {
        // If the person already has a score in dict, then add this new score to it.
        dict[person.name] = score + person.score
    } else {
        // If this is the first score for this person, then add the person to dict.
        dict[person.name] = person.score
    }
}
```

Next, we will used [`subscript(_:default:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/2894528-subscript) operator to combine the two parts of the if conditional.

```swift
var dict = [String: Int]()

for person in people {
    // Add the new score to the person's existing score. If there is no existing
    // score, then default to 0 and add the new score.
    dict[person.name, default: 0] += person.score
}
```

Finally, use [`reduce(into:_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/3126956-reduce) to get rid of the for loop (see [no raw loops segment of C++ Seasoning](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/Cpp-Seasoning))

```swift
// Reduce people into a dictionary of names and cumulative scores.
let dict = people.reduce(into: [String: Int]()) { result, person in
    result[person.name, default: 0] += person.score
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Jeffery. I was looking for how to use reduce like you showed me. It helped me a lot.